# Pymongo node descendants with a specific order

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

[image: Mongo tree]

Consider that I have a tree in MongoDB as seen in the picture.

What I'd like to do is getting node descendants in a specific order.

```
def descendants(nodeID):
    descendants = []
    stack = []

    item = vt.comments.find_one({'_id': nodeID })
    stack.append(item)
    stack.sort(key=lambda x: x['order'])

    while(len(stack) > 0):
        currentNode = stack.pop()
        children = vt.comments.find({'parent': currentNode["_id"] })

        for child in children:
            descendants.append(child['_id'])
            stack.append(child)
            stack.sort(key=lambda x: x['order'])

    print(descendants)
```

My program is similiar to this and when I call this function 
 like this `descendants(0)` it's output is similiar to this:

> [1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 14, 15, 8, 9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 6, 7, 16, 17, 18, 19]

But what I'd like to do is access items in this order:

> [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 8, 9, 10, 11, 3, 12, 16, 17, 18, 19, 13, 14, 15 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as excepted:

```
def descendants(nodeID):

    descendants = []
    stack = []

    item = vt.comments.find_one({'_id': nodeID })
    stack.append(item)
    stack.sort(key=lambda x: x['order'], reverse=True)

    while(len(stack) > 0):
        currentNode = stack.pop()
        descendants.append(child['_id'])
        children = vt.comments.find({'parent': currentNode["_id"] })

        for child in children:
            stack.append(child)
            stack.sort(key=lambda x: x['order'], reverse=True)

    print(descendants)
```